# How to change storage vdi size

Tags: virtualbox

On windows host I changed the vdi size by typing - `VBoxManage.exe modifyhd vdi_file --resize 50000`

It was completed and I can see the new size of the file in my windows explorer.

Inside the settings of the virtualbox it shows that the `Ubuntu.vdi` is 48.83GB with actual size of 24.66GB.

But when I try to install vivado I receive a message that there is not enough disk space on `/opt/Xilinx` to install.  Under the Disk Space Required it says space required - 15.21GB  space available - 11.05GB. Should be approximately 22GB available after resizing the `vdi` file.

Why doesn't the install see the size increase when virtualbox does see it?

Comment: Ok, I installed gparted in Ubuntu ran it and I get a window showing the /dev/sda1 partition ext4 file system with a size of 28.93gb.  I select this entry and try to resize it but I am unable to do so.

Comment: You have to run it in a live environment.  You can't resize the partition if it's mounted.  Boot the virtual machine with the disk image you used to create it, and select "try ubuntu".  Gparted should be included on the live disk, and you can fix it from there.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the size of the disk does not automatically increase the size of the partitions on it.  You have to use a tool like `gparted` to do that.  Once you start `gparted` it will show you all the unused space, and you simply drag the partition boundaries around to fill that up.

Comment: Not on a virtual disk.

Comment: Yes, I certainly had to do that on my virtual machine.  And it appears that the OP needs to do it as well.